Adding authentication headers to SOAP request C#
I need to make a request to an endpoint so to get the fines associated with a car plate number, using SOAP.
I have generated my GjobaWebService class from a .wsdl file and to my understanding i need to provide the credentials to authenticate. I tried passing them through a NetworkCredentials class yet i didn't get a successful response, instead receiving error "Invalid Credentials".
Do i need to include "Basic " before the hashedCredentials or any other change or i'm just providing wrong credentials?
protected void FunctionCall(object sender, EventArgs e){
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
 
            string hashedCredentials = "";//pretend there's a base64 credential here

            //Url = "https://10.10.22.52:443/EGjobaBridgeWeb/GjobaWebService";

            string decodedCredentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(hashedCredentials));

            string[] credentials = decodedCredentials.Split(':');

            string username = credentials[0];

            string password = credentials[1];

            try
            {
                GjobaWebService service = new GjobaWebService();

                service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(password, username);

                string plate = TxtRefNo.Text;

                ticket[] tickets = service.merrMjet(plate);

 

                foreach (ticket t in tickets)
                {
                    TxtRefNo.Text += $"Ticket members: Vlera: {t.Vlera} , Data: {t.Data}, Pronari: {t.MjetiPronari}";

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TxtTest.Text = $"Error: {ex.Message}";
            }
}

